# Is it possible to set up a single Tableau workbook that pulls different data based on the user (or group)?

Tags: tableau-api

We use Tableau to create self-serve reports for various internal groups.  The reports are identical in structure and style, but have different source data.  As an example: European sales YTD and North American sales YTD.

For reasons we can't just have one workbook that each group then selects a dropdown for their data, they have to be separate workbooks. There are maybe a dozen of these.

We find ourselves *constantly* catching bugs or adding new components, and then having to go do it 10+ identical times in all the workbooks.  Or worse, making a hot-fix and then not doing it for the others until it becomes an issue.

Ideally we'd make the change once in one master workbook and it'd cascade to all the others.  Is something like that possible in Tableau?

Comment: Read this (user-based filtering): https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/publish_userfilters.htm

Comment: Nice!  Not sure if it's a total solution yet, one of our "reasons" is extract size, but there might be a way to jam them all in there.